# Rspec - How to stub a 3rd party exception

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rspec, rspec3

I'm trying to test that I'm able to capture these AWS exceptions:

```
begin
  s3_client = S3Client.new
  s3_file = s3_client.write_s3_file(bucket, file_name, file_contents)
rescue AWS::Errors::ServerError, AWS::Errors::ClientError => e
  # do something
end
```

My Rspec 3 code:

```
expect_any_instance_of(S3Client).to receive(:write_s3_file).and_raise(AWS::Errors::ServerError)
```

But when I test this stub, I get a TypeError:

```
exception class/object expected
```

Do I have to include AWS::Errors::ServerError? If so, how would I do that? I'm using the aws-sdk-v1 gem.

Thanks.

Comment: In what line are you getting `TypeError`?

Comment: ../gems/rspec-mocks-3.1.3/lib/rspec/mocks/message_expectation.rb:194

Comment: Your code seems fine for me. The only concern I have it's requiring s3client and AWS stack libraries. Just for experiment, try to replace S3Client by any class rails knows about by default (any model for example) and AWS::Errors... by StandardError and run your test.

Comment: @Alexander, yea that tested fine. If I replace AWS::Errors::ServerError with AWS::Errors::RandomError (which doesn't exist), then I get: "uninitialized constant AWS::Errors::RandomError". So it sounds like AWS::Errors::ServerError is definitely included. Any other ideas? Or maybe a different approach to testing this? Thanks.

Comment: @Slowfib: Have you found a solution? I'm stuck at a similar problem.

Comment: Not specifically for this, but including the S3Client inside the class was making it too tightly coupled and harder to test. Davey's answer below is probably the best solution, but I would instead pass the client in via the initialize on the class. This way way you can pass a double in your test and mock whatever method and exceptions you want. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build in a port, and then inject a stubbed out object that is just dying to throw you an error. Let me explain:

```
class ImgService
  def set_client(client=S3Client.new)
    @client = client
  end

  def client
    @client ||= S3Client.new
  end

  def write(bucket, file_name, file_contents)
    begin
      @client.write_s3_file(bucket, file_name, file_contents)
    rescue AWS::Errors::ServerError, AWS::Errors::ClientError => e
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

test:

```
describe "rescuing an AWS::Error" do
  before :each do
    @fake_client = double("fake client")
    allow(@fake_client).to receive(:write_s3_file).and_raise(AWS::Errors::ServerError)

    @img_service = ImgService.new
    @img_service.set_client(@fake_client)
  end
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having to require the specific files with those exceptions, you can stub the exceptions in your spec file:

```
stub_const("AWS::Errors::ServerError", StandardError)
stub_const("AWS::Errors::ClientError", StandardError)
```

Then your `expect` will work.

This also works well for testing Rails exceptions such as `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`.